# Cypress request does not first time when test run

Tags: cypress

Hey guys I have an interesting issue.

I have a test where my request successfully is completed, but the state in-app and DB are not changed.

My case looks like this:

I create User (first, last name) using cy.request() - graphQL request
Then I run a second request where I update the User and add a phone number.

Both requests are successful, but when I open this User, the phone number is not visible.

Then I click at reload-icon inside cypress browser "run this test again", and test runs again. Again requests are successful. But this time everything is fine:
User is created and phone number is added to this User

I also tried

```
 retries: {
        runMode: 2,
        openMode: 1,
      },
```

Nothing helps, any1 has idea ?

---

By reload, I mean here when I click reload.

[image]

---

@Tobias - Actually I am not doing it like that.

I have commands for lets say

cy.createUser() cy.updateUser()

I just call them like that, one after another. I thought it could be that I need cy.wait() in between but nothing helps.

It's just always the first time when a test runs it fails, then if I keep reloading the test browsers, it never fails. That why its confusing.

Comment: try to add cy.reload() after the requests.

Comment: I did, also does not work :/

Comment: Can you share project source code?
Any way I can run this test on my machine?

Comment: @VitorAraujo sadly no. I will try this week those chained requests and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you chained the requests in sequence?

```
cy.request({...}).then((response) => {
      cy.request({...}).then((response) => {

     })
})
```

Maybe you can add a more detailed code example.

Comment: Thank you Tobias and Kkhan, I will try this approach and let you know. Sorry for the mess. I am not super familiar with stackoverflow yet :)

Comment: I've tried also with your suggestion but its the same :) Might be that something with my app is not processing correct or so. 
Thank you for help everyone